# Creating Resfresh Token for login in Mobile App by Laravel Passport using Google API Auth

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, laravel-passport

I`m developing mobile app and I have auth by Google in this app.
When user login by Google I want to make response which include access token and refresh token from Laravel Passport.

I don`t have problem with access token.
I created it by Laravel Passport.

```
$token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
```

I want create refresh token also, but I have a problem.
When I create refresh token by Laravel Passport one of all required param this is $password, however Google don`t give me this param in his response.

How I can create refresh token?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a refresh token in Laravel Passport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330402/how-do-i-get-a-refresh-token-in-laravel-passport)