How to Generate Refresh Token in Laravel 11 Passport?
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // Validate the input
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        "email" => "required|email",
        "password" => "required",
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            "status" => 0,
            "message" => "Validation error",
            "data" => $validator->errors()
        ]);
    }

    // Check if user exists
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();


    // If user doesn't exist or password is incorrect
    if (!$user || !\Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        return response()->json([
            "status" => 0,
            "message" => "Invalid credentials",
        ]);
    }
    // Create an access token
    $accessToken = $user->createToken('API Token')->accessToken;

    // Prepare the response data
    $response = [
        'token' => $accessToken,
        // 'refresh_token' => i want to generate refresh token,
        'user' => $user->name,
        'email' => $user->email,
    ];

    return response()->json([
        "status" => 1,
        "message" => "User logged in successfully.",
        "data" => $response
    ]);
}

I'm currently using Laravel 11 with Laravel Passport, and I'm only getting the access token. Is there a way to create a refresh token that I can keep in a secure cookie with Laravel Passport? The idea is to use that refresh token when my access token runs out instead of making users log in again. I’d like to use the access token to get a new refresh token instead.

Could you please check the How to ask section on StackOverflow? It’s important to explain your issue, your research, and what you expect.

Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330402/how-do-i-get-a-refresh-token-in-laravel-passport

@skdishansachin sorry for that, i already researched then post my question on this platform.
i want to generate refresh token on new laravel 11 way. user login after create store  refresh token in secure cookie. if user token is expired then just call refresh token API. user don't need login again. i hope understand my concern.
Don't use the OAuth password grant type
https://www.scottbrady91.com/oauth/why-the-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-type-is-not-authentication-nor-suitable-for-modern-applications

If you've done your research, it would help to include it in your question. Mentioning "Laravel 11 way" doesn't make sense, as Passport remains unchanged in Laravel 11. Check the release notes for Laravel 11 if you need to. Please be specific about your problem.

I think you have to create your own custom logic to manage the refresh token in this context. You also have to create your own migration and model and change your login function to include that refresh token in the response. If you want those coding examples, tell me. I will add those as an answer to this.

@HarshadevaPriyankaraBandara, could you explain how to create a proper API using Laravel 11 with Passport?
I need help with the following four APIs:

Register
Login
Refresh Token
Logout

I'm not experienced in Laravel, so could you explain the process and suggest the proper way to implement them? Please provide a detailed flow on how to implement these APIs correctly.
